# Maven: Missing Files in modules

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I'm using Eclipse and I have **Maven** project with **jar** and ***war*** modules. I exported it to my github acc. and when I import it from Git it runs correctly but something is not like i wanted to. In my Parent module i have all the files, but situation changes in my jars and war module.

For example in **src** folder i have two folders, **java** and webapp, in **war** called "psy-webapp" **java** is missing. I read something about it, and i must change the path to let maven see all folders/files right? I'm also sending link to github project and a screenshot to see what i mean.

**Github:**https://github.com/jakubjaroszek/ltc

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ugk.jpg)

Comment: From the screenshot, the `psy-webapp` has a `/src/main/java` folder as well. What does that consist of?

Comment: Most important is not to checkin .settings / .classpath / .project cause those files are generated during the import into Eclipse.

Comment: @nullpointer Folder is in POM project  but i can't see it in WAR module  i send screenshot again indicating  in what folder I don't see "java" folder. http://i68.tinypic.com/fxxqxe.jpg